# Kendo Treeview checkbox checked together with selected node

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I manage to make checkbox only can be checked at 1 time, but I need help to find the solution if checkbox is checked the node will be selected as well `k-state-selected`. Appreciate your help!

[Here I provide a simple demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/elAJecEs/2)

Comment: You want only to check one item in node? What child should be checked if you select parent item?

Comment: sorry I wasn`t expected that things. I edit the demo correctly based on my situation, No parents and child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.406/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.406/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
    <div id="treeview"></div>
    <script>
        $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes: true,
            check: function(e){
              var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);
              var rootNodes = $("#treeview").getKendoTreeView().dataSource.data();
              traverse(rootNodes, function(node) {
                if (node != dataItem) {
                  node.set("checked", false);
                  //node.select($());
                  //node.select().find("span.k-state-selected")
                }
              });
            },
           select: function(e) {
              var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);
              dataItem.checked = true;
              $(e.node).find('input').prop('checked', 'checked');
              this.trigger('check', e);
            },
          dataSource: [ { id: 3, text: "about.html" },
                       { id: 4, text: "index.html"},
                       { id: 5, text: "logo.png"},                        
                       { id: 7, text: "mockup.jpg" },
                       { id: 8, text: "Research.pdf"},
                       { id: 10, text: "February.pdf" },
                       { id: 11, text: "March.pdf" },
                       { id: 12, text: "April.pdf" }]
        });
      
        function traverse(nodes, callback) {
          for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            var node = nodes[i];
            var children = node.hasChildren && node.children.data();
            callback(node);
            if (children) {
              traverse(children, callback);
            }
          }
        }
      
       $("#treeview").on('change', 'input', function() {
          let $li = $(this).closest('li');
          $("#treeview").data('kendoTreeView').select($li);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added the following code:

```
// To the grid options
select: function(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);
    dataItem.checked = true;
    $(e.node).find('input').prop('checked', 'checked');
    this.trigger('check', e);
},

// After grid initialization
$("#treeview").on('change', 'input', function() {
    let $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $("#treeview").data('kendoTreeView').select($li);
});
```

The first snippet makes sure that selecting an item by clicking it's label, the checkbox will be checked as well. That event also call `check` event to uncheck other items.

The last one makes sure a checkbox changed will be trigger the `select` event, doing the same as above.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for  answer. Do you mind to help me with my another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137386/kendo-multiselect-make-value-to-be-selected-and-disable). I'm really appreciate your help.