# Kendo MultiSelect make value to be selected and disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

Need help here. I create a simple demo here and what I want to achieve from `dataBound` if `checked='yes'` node is selected and disable(apply k-state-disable) from edit. I try to set `(selected,true)` & `(disabled,true)` but seem it not working.

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/aDaxozUX)

```js
<select id="multiselect"></select>

$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataSource: {
    data: [
      {id:1, Name: "John 1", checked: 'no'},
      {id:2, Name: "John 2", checked: 'yes'},
      {id:3, Name: "John 3", checked: 'no'},
      {id:4, Name: "John 4", checked: 'yes'},
      {id:5, Name: "John 5", checked: 'no'},
      {id:6, Name: "John 6", checked: 'no'}
    ]
  },
  dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "id", 
    dataBound: function(e) {
    var multiselect = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    var x = multiselect.dataSource.view();

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (x[i].checked == "yes") {
        //x[i].set("selected", true);
        //x[i].set("disabled ", true);
        //x[i].prop("disabled", true).addClass("k-state-disabled");
      } 
    }
  },

});
```

Comment: So to clarify, you want to prepopulate selected items and disable multiselct from adding or removing items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to suggest another way for achieve that. Avoid changing DOM in `dataBound` whenever possible. So I would like to suggest using [`itemTemplate`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/configuration/itemtemplate) option and [`select`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/events/select) event:

You can apply `.k-state-disabled` class within the `itemTemplate` option:

```
itemTemplate: '<span # if (data.checked === "yes") { #class="k-state-disabled"# } #>#: Name #</span>'
```

That will make the option look like disabled. But it is still possible to select it in the list, so you can use `select` event to prevent that:

```
select: function(e) {
    if (e.dataItem.checked === 'yes') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
},
```

Using `e.preventDefault()` inside that event will prevent user from selecting the option which matches the condition.

[Updated Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aDaxozUX/10)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `select` and `deselect` events:

```
    function onDeselect(e) {
        if (e.dataItem.checked == 'yes') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }  



    function onSelect(e) {
        if(e.dataItem.checked == 'yes') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };  

$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  select: onSelect,
  deselect: onDeselect,
  //...
});
```

[working demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@tata.leona/AxiZADuX)